# iOS: Compare pressed button to label text

Tags: objective-c, ios, syntax

I have a simple function to see if the button touched is the same as the text of a label:

```
- (IBAction) checkIt:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    if(button.getText() == randomNumber.text){
        randomNumber.text = @"Nice.";
    }
    else{
        randomNumber.text = @"Try Again";
    }
}
```

Where "randomNumber" is a label. However, this doesn't work. I'm a Cocoa/Objective-C beginner and I'm not sure what the proper syntax is.

I'm open to any addition information you would like/think is helpful to idiots like me. :)

Four buttons are mapped to this function: Cow, Pig, Frog, Sheep. The "randomNumber" label is randomized from an array of strings "Cow,Frog"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(button.getText() == randomNumber.text)
```

This will never work because this is not the right way to compare strings. '==' only compares the memory address, the NSString method `isEqualToString` actually compares the strings.

Also, I would get the button text by using the property, titleLabel.text. So, I would try like this:

```
- (IBAction) checkIt:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:randomNumber.text]){
        randomNumber.text = @"Nice.";
    }
    else{
        randomNumber.text = @"Try Again";
    }
}
```

Comment: Super. Why do we always do 'if([...])' and not just 'if(...)'?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing in the () for comparison. In this case we are using an objective-C method, so we have to do that. If you were comparing simple integers x & y it would look like this: if (x = y).

Comment: By the way, you might want to check the server config for your website :)

Comment: Oh, yeah. I'm in school and haven't had time to update. :/ A bit negligent, I know.

Comment: Uh, this isn't producing any errors, but it isn't functional...what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? Does the method run at all?

Comment: The method runs, yes. but the conditional isn't working? Is it case sensitive?